# Know difference between two angles with only their sine and cosine?

Tags: python, python-3.x, math, python-3.6

Hi recently I was writing a program with a bunch dots that the player had to avoid. The dots changed direction, but can't turn too much in a given timeframe.

I had a method of doing this but was inefficient as I had to arcsine, knowing the cosed angle and sined angle, then sine and cosine that angle. I thought of just returning the cosine and sined angle, but theres one problem. Once I received the cosine and sine, I need too know if it is too different from my current state.

With the angle this would be easy as I would just have too see the difference, here's a model program,(the code I currently have uses the angle, and isn't very helpful). I have tried graphing sine and cosine and trying to observe any patterns, none obvious showed up.

```
import math
def sendTargRot():
    #I actually use a fairly long method to find it's current rotation, but a random.random() is a fair replacement, so in my real thing there would be no angle calculation
    pretendAngle =  math.pi*random.random()-math.pi
    pretendCosedX = math.cos(pretendAngle)
    pretendSinedX = math.sin(pretendAngle)
def changeDotAngle():
    targRot = sendTargRot
    #make sure targRot is not too much from current rotation
    #do stuff with the angle, change dot's rotation
```

If you want to just give me an algorithm without code that is just as acceptable!

EDIT: I can't really change sendTargRot so it gives a proper rotation, because that would require me knowing the current angle, and really it's just moving the problem.

Comment: I think the problem here is that you're going to have to throw in an `arcsin` or an `arccos` somewhere. Even if you use some clever trig identities to get the numbers to line up, you'll still have to `arcsin` it at the end because `sinx` and `cosx` are scalar quantities, not angles, so any manipulation done with them will inherently result in a scalar. And you want the difference in angles.

Comment: You could use the sines & cosines of 2 angles to calculate the tan of the difference between the 2 angles. However, tan(x)=tan(pi+x), so just using the tan you won't be able to tell the difference between 2 vectors that are close to each other and 2 vectors that point in almost opposite directions. But you can disambiguate that using the signs of your sines and cosines.

Comment: Why don't you precompute the random number necessary to have the pretendangle within your limit. Then use random number within that range.

Comment: Could you specify more clear - what data are done, and what value you want to get?

Comment: @mamun the random number was an example, in my game it's not a random number, but a rather long process that was not necessary to post on SO.

Comment: @MBo Basically I know the co-ordinates of two points on a unit circle, without trigonometry, I would like to find the difference between their angles.

Answer (score 1):

To get angle between two vectors you can use `atan2` function

```
 angle = Math.atan2(a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x, a.x * b.x + a.y * b.y)
```

if you already have got cosines and sines (the same as coordinates on unit circle):

```
 angle = Math.atan2(cos(a) * sin(b) - sin(a) * cos(b), cos(a) * cos(b) + sin(a) * sin(b))
```

This approach gives angle needed to rotate `a` until it coincides with `b` accounting for direction (in range `-Pi..Pi`)

Comment: is atan2 a trignometric function? because if so that kind of kills the whole point. I know how to find the angle using arcsine/arctan

Comment: There no way to go from coordinate space into angle space without trig. functions.  But perhaps you really need cos and sin (of resulting angle) rather than angle inself - in this case first and second arguments of atan2 are sin and cos. It is common approach in reflection-based games and similar stuff - you always have components of unit direction vector and never operate with angle.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but I unfortunately can't accept it, as it still uses trigonometry.

Comment: Once again - it is impossible to get angle without trigonometry (or some approximation). Only differerence angle sine and cosine:  `DiffAngleSin = a.x * b.y - a.y * b.x`